# AngularUI-Bootstrap Typeahead: Grouping titles by type

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, typehead

I am implementing typeahead using AngularUI-Bootstrap. I need to show the results grouped based on some values coming from the database. Here's a example of result

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "type_1",
    "titles": [{
        "id": 1,
        "label": "title_1"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "label": "title_2"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "label": "title_3"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "type_2",
    "titles": [{
        "id": 4,
        "label": "title_4"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "label": "title_6"
    }]
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "type_3",
    "titles": [{
        "id": 8,
        "label": "title_8"
    }, {
        "id": 9,
        "label": "title_9"
    }]
}]
```

- How can grouping titles by type in AngularUI-Bootstrap Typeahead

Comment: The documentation has an example showing how to define a custom template for the dropdown menu. Use something similar and use two nested ng-repeat to loop through your types and then your titles. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: your plunk is empty

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, but how can i define custom template for Array grouped by type and select only title no type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JB Nizet** is right, you should use a custom template ([default](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/template/typeahead/typeahead-match.html)). Look at

```
// view
<script type="text/ng-template" id="typeahead-match.html">
  <div ng-if="match.model.isGroup">{{match.label}}</div>
  <a ng-if="!match.model.isGroup" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;{{match.label}}
  </a>
</script>

<input
  type="text"
  ng-model="selected"
  uib-typeahead="item as item.label for item in getItems($viewValue)"
  class="form-control"
  typeahead-template-url="typeahead-match.html">

// controller
myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "label": "type_1",
    "titles": [{
      "id": 1,
      "label": "title_1"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "label": "title_2"
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "label": "title_3"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "label": "type_2",
    "titles": [{
      "id": 4,
      "label": "title_4"
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "label": "title_6"
    }]
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "label": "type_3",
    "titles": [{
      "id": 8,
      "label": "title_8"
    }, {
      "id": 9,
      "label": "title_9"
    }]
  }];

  $scope.getItems = function(text) {
    var result = [];

    _.each(data, function(group) {
      result.push({
        label: group.label,
        isGroup: true
      });

      _.each(group.titles, function(item) {
        if(_.startsWith(item.label, text)) {
          result.push(item);
        }
      });

      if(result && result[result.length-1].isGroup) {
        result.pop();
      }
    });

    return result;
  };
}]);
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/p24venko/)